# Importing data from an Excel file in SSIS

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm running a job in SQL Server Management Studio which takes an Excel file from a SharePoint repository and dumps the data in the a database table.

The job runs fine on my local machine which has Microsoft Access. When I deploy the package on the development system, I get numerous errors (Displayed below)

I have read numerous blogs which detail on the cause of the error, which is usually:
1. Permissions on the folder path; 2. Running the step in 32 bit run-time mode; 3. Having the Microsoft Access Database Engine or related connection manager.

I have checked for all of these things, but I'm still not able to get the package running in my development system. Here is a snapshot of my errors:

[image: Error Description]

Any ideas on what I could be missing? 
Thanks!

Comment: (On behalf of @gofr1) Can you show a connection string of this package? What provider do you use? If it works on your PC I recommend to check the credentials that you provided for the connection.